# create regex to match a string with a letter followed by fixed number of digits

Tags: c#, regex

We have one of use case where we need to validate some `Uid` with following constraint:

> Uid of lenght 5 in form **annnnn** where **a** is any letter other than `A`, `B`, `D` and `E`. And **n** is any number from `0` to `9`.

So I have create new method which will validate same and working for as expected.

```
/// <summary>
/// Validate Uid of lenght 5 in form annnnn where ‘a’ is any letter other than A, B, D and E.
/// </summary>
/// <param name="value"></param>
/// <returns></returns>
private static bool IsValidUid( string value )
{
    bool returnValue = false;

    if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(value) == false && value.Length == 5)
    {
        char firstChar = value[0];
        bool firstCharFailed = false;

        switch (firstChar)
        {
            case 'A':
            case 'B':
            case 'D':
            case 'E':
                firstCharFailed = true;
                break;
        }

        if (firstCharFailed == false)
        {
            string remainingStr = value.Substring(1, 4);

            int numb;

            if (int.TryParse(remainingStr, out numb) == true)
            {
                returnValue = true;
            }
        }
    }

    return returnValue;
}
```

But it could be effectively done via regular expression. Since I am bad with it, I need help to create one for me! Thanks in advance!!

Comment: `^[CF-Za-z]\d{4}$`?

Comment: @CertainPerformance First char other than: `A`,`B`,`D` and `E`

Comment: @AnkushMadankar Doesn't his pattern do just this?

Comment: "But it could be effectively done via regular expression" How do you come to his conclusion? Apart from this do you have a specific problem with your code? Doesn´t it do what you want?

Comment: Can we have pattern with except those chars? It now considering range between?

Comment: @CertainPerformance's pattern does this. If you only want upper case letters on the first character use this: `^[CF-Z]\d{4}$`

Comment: If the `C` is missing you can just add it like : `^[CF-Za-z]\d{4}$`. For learning basic regex I recommend [Regexone](https://regexone.com/), i'm not affilied or anything but thats what work best simple exemple that people can try in live. Just enought to understand the basic.

Comment: @HimBromBeere So should I keep this working code and skip regex for string?  Sorry about perforce conclusion..

Comment: Well, you should be carefull when changing code that allready works. You potentially *break* it un-intendently. On the other hand it doesn´t give you a real advantage. You have to decide on your if it´s worth the afford.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> where ‘a’ is any letter other than A, B, D and E.

So in this case you need to specify the set of letters that are allowed

`[a-zF-ZC]` => meaning all letters are in the range a-z and F-Z should be matched, also C should be matched

> And 'n' is any number from 0 to 9.

`\d` matches a digit or you can use `[0-9]`

> of lenght 5 in form annnnn

`\d{4}` specifies the amount of the preceding character that is ought to be matched

One last thing has to be done. You need to specify, that `a` is supposed to be at the beginning of the string and that the string ends after the 5-th character:

`^` denotes the start of a string
`$` denotes the end of a string.

So combined it would look like this:

```
string pattern = @"^[a-zF-ZC]\d{4}$
```

or using the range for the digits:

```
string pattern = @"^[a-zF-ZC][0-9]{4}$
```

Here is an [overview of the regex patterns](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/regular-expressions) with examples and explanations

Here is a [site where you can test and try out your regex pattern](https://regex101.com/r/cK4Iy9/1). Fiddle around with it to get to know it. It helps

**EDIT:**

the `[...]` denote a set of characters that will be matched. A Range is denoted using the `-` sign like in `a-z`, `A-F` or `5-9`. Any other character ca be simply put into the set:

`[abcdefgxyz]` will match only those specified letters!

The set and the ranges can be combined

`[CF-SX-Z]` will match `C` or all capital letters between `F` and `S` and between `X` and `Z`. I hope it get more clear now

Comment: Missing the `C`

Comment: @DragandDrop Thank you

Comment: What if have more than one char need to skip between range of A-Z? All need to be capital letters

Comment: @AnkushMadankar sorry, I don't understand you. "All need to be capital letters –" I thought it is always only 1 letter followed by digits

Comment: @AnkushMadankar if you have more then 1 letter you can specify the amount using the `{ }` brackets. as I wrote in my explanation

Comment: I assume he means that the first letter has to be in capital.

Comment: @AnkushMadankar if you don't want to allow small letters, remove them from the pattern. Regex will only try to match what is specified inside the pattern. So simply leave `[CF-Z]`

Comment: I need to skip letter `D`, `I`, `T`

Comment: @AnkushMadankar any other additional constraint that you did not mention in your post? ;) I will edit my post to try and make it more clear. So that you can figure out this case on your own

Comment: @MongZhu Thanks for the explaining it and the reference which provided in ans, help appreciated!